# crypto hardcoded key can bee seen in devtools, is it safe

Tags: javascript, cryptojs

```
import crypto from 'crypto-browserify'

const hash = crypto.createHash('sha1');
hash.update(process.env.VUE_APP_EPROC_SALT);
const iv = Buffer.from(process.env.VUE_APP_EPROC_IV.split(','));
const key = hash.digest().slice(0, 16);

function encrypt(text) {
  if (!text) return '';
  try {
    let mykey = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-cbc', key, iv);
    return mykey.update(text, 'utf8', 'hex') + mykey.final('hex');

  } catch (ex) {
    return '';
  }
}

function decrypt(text) {
  if (!text) return '';
  try {
    let mykey = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-cbc', key, iv);
    return mykey.update(text, 'hex', 'utf8') + mykey.final('utf8');
  } catch (ex) {
    return '';
  }
}
```

[in devtools , in source scoped i can see the key and iv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLYbk.png)

can i hide the key and iv , or should i change the encryption method to encryption method that safer from what i use right now

Comment: Might need to know more about what you do with the encrypted data, but, yeah, you might as well not encrypt it if the decryption key is public, which it is.

Comment: how are you using it? Is it for like a chat, or client/server communication?

Comment: @GarrGodfrey i continue my company current project , he use it to fetching api . so they use the same encrypt decrypt in both frontend backend. the purpose is to avoid user can see the data in devtools network. but come another problem that i write in here

Comment: So it is really just obfuscation. It is harder to get in and see the data, but there is no way to make it impossible. Everything the browser does is easily viewable, and they can even step through code line by line and look at individual variables.

Comment: If they want the data to be a secret, don't send it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`createCipheriv` is useful for a single party encryption, and typically used with a password, or user supplied key of some sort. Password would need to be supplied every time it is decrypted or encrypted.

If you are doing two party encryption, like from client to server or peer-to-peer, you really need a public/private key system. Each party sends the public key to the other, and the data is encrypted using the public key, and decrypted at the receiving end using the private key, which is never accessible to  any other party (never sent over internet).

Unfortunately, crypto-js doesn't seem to support public/private key methods (like RSA, AES). You can use something like https://openpgpjs.org/